# Convert from amount=Decimal('123') to amount=123 in python 3.6

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am looking for one line code where I should be able to convert set of values which are in the format

```
amount = Decimal('123') to amount = 123.
```

I tried following

```
'amount': int(json.dumps(str(transaction['amount'])))
```

That gave me

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

I tried this too

```
'amount': json.dumps(str(transaction['amount']))
```

It gave me

```
'amount': '"5000.00"'
```

Can someone help me to find a way to get the desired value? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Is `Decimal('123')` a string? Because if it just a python `decimal.Decimal` then `int(Decimal('123'))` would do the job.

Comment: perfect! @AChampion! it worked. Thanks! I should have checked the type. Appreciate your help!